# Can you use a smart speaker as a microphone/speaker combo for a normal PC?

Tags: audio, microphone, speakers, cortana

I am working on a project where I want to build a HTPC/gaming pc/NAS combo that sits in my living room close to my TV. It will run Windows 10 and it will be controllable by an XBOX One controller (and if it's needed, a wireless keyboard and mouse).

It's not a priority, but I would like to bake in some *smart* support. Cortana is already on-board Windows 10, and she is capable of completing the tasks that I want (Spotify, find stuff on Netflix, launch Steam). The head-scratch I am faced with, is a way to talk to her - which sounds more romantic than it is. I need a good microphone that detects sound in the whole room, and I need a good speaker either way. (I am planning to send music and Cortana output to this device, and movie/game sounds to the TV. Luckily Windows 10 allows you to change the input/output for each app - including Cortana.) So of course my eyes and thoughts went out to existing smart speakers, specifically Amazon's Echo - but alternatives are fine as well.

The thing is, though, that I don't need, nor want, Alexa in my life at all - building on the romantic setting here. My question then is, is there a way to use devices such as the Echo as a smart speaker without any shipped assistants? Basically use the Echo's hardware as an IO device and not using its built-in smart capabilities, but leaving those to Cortana? Put crudely, can you crop Alexa from the picture? (Completely disable her, don't let her talk to the cloud either.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A search on "Echo Skills" showed no 'skill' (the apps which control an Echo) created to permit this, and one source [suggests it cannot](https://www.reddit.com/r/alexa/comments/7m6428/what_can_an_echo_do_without_internet_access/). However, proving a negative ain't doable, and sources to learn what you could do with it include the [Alexa Skills Kit](https://developer.amazon.com/alexa-skills-kit/learn) as well as [this example on GitHub](https://github.com/toddmedema/echo).